# how do I access return data after coming back from Java method

Tags: java, methods, return-value

> I'm a Java newbie, and this is a real basic, basic question, so please don't
>     miss the tree for the forest.
>     I just need to know how to access the data coming back from the method

```
    private static int toInt( String number )
    {
        int multiplicand = 0;
        // do stuff to figure out a multiplicand
        return multiplicand;
    }

    public static void main( String[ ] args )
    {
        int anotherVariable = 53;
        toInt( args[ 0 ] );
```

> So, what do I say here after I've come back from the toInt method in order to access what is in multiplicand?
>   Lets say I want to multiply what came back in multiplicand * anotherVariable.
>   I cannot use multiplicand because the editor just says "cannot resolve multiplcand to a variable."
>
> Thank you in advance to all the great programmers with the patience to tolerate us newbies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you assign the result of the function invocation to a variable, and then use that.

`int result = toInt ("1");`

You can now use `result` as you see fit; it contains whatever you returned in the method, which was the value of `multiplicand`.  So in your case, you can now do

`int anotherResult = result * anotehrVariable;`

Note you can also do

`int anotherResult = toInt(args[0]) * anotherVariable;`

without assigning the result of your invocation of `toInt` to an intermediary variable.

I prefer to assign function invocations to variables; makes debugging easier.  If you want to use the result more than once, it's almost always better to use a variable.

Comment: +1: But have another look, he's passing args[0] which is a String.